# What is the pandas equivalent of dplyr summarize/aggregate by multiple functions?

Tags: python, r, pandas, group-by, summarize

I want to convert my R code using `dplyr` package into pandas where I group-by and perform multiple summarizations.

Here is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col1':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
    'col2':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
     'col3':[-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,0]
    }
)
result = []
for k,v in data.groupby('col1'):
    result.append([k, max(v['col2']), min(v['col3'])])
print pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['col1', 'col2_agg', 'col3_agg'])
```

Issues:

- too verbose
- probably can be optimized and efficient. (I rewrote a `for-loop groupby` implementation into `groupby.agg` and the performance enhancement was huge).

In R the equivalent code would be:

```
data %>% groupby(col1) %>% summarize(col2_agg=max(col2), col3_agg=min(col3))
```

Also, what is the equivalent of `groupby().summarize(newcolumn=max(col2 * col3))` i.e. an aggregation/summarization where the function is a compound function of 2+ columns?

Comment: You can check [here](http://pythonhosted.org/pandas-ply/)

Comment: Doing a manual iteration over a `groupby` result like `for k,v in data.groupby('col1'):` is always a code smell that you should be doing `aggregate()`. pandas can do multiple aggregations too. See the tutorials.

Comment: Another possible issue when migrating to pandas is that you didn't like the index pandas returns on a groupby object (and by default, pandas gives you a MultiIndex if it's a groupby multiple columns, unless you specify `as_index=False`). But in your case you're only grouping by `col1`

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The equivalent of

```
df %>% groupby(col1) %>% summarize(col2_agg=max(col2), col3_agg=min(col3))
```

is

```
df.groupby('col1').agg({'col2': 'max', 'col3': 'min'})
```

which returns

```
      col2  col3
col1            
1        5    -5
2        9    -9
```

The returning object is a pandas.DataFrame with an index called `col1` and columns named `col2` and `col3`. By default, when you group your data pandas sets the grouping column(s) as index for efficient access and modification. However, if you don't want that, there are two alternatives to set `col1` as a column.

- Pass `as_index=False`:

  ```
  df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).agg({'col2': 'max', 'col3': 'min'})
  ```
- Call `reset_index`:

  ```
  df.groupby('col1').agg({'col2': 'max', 'col3': 'min'}).reset_index()
  ```

both yield

```
col1  col2  col3           
   1     5    -5
   2     9    -9
```

You can also pass multiple functions to `groupby.agg`.

```
agg_df = df.groupby('col1').agg({'col2': ['max', 'min', 'std'], 
                                 'col3': ['size', 'std', 'mean', 'max']})
```

This also returns a DataFrame but now it has a MultiIndex for columns.

```
     col2               col3                   
      max min       std size       std mean max
col1                                           
1       5   1  1.581139    5  1.581139   -3  -1
2       9   0  3.535534    5  3.535534   -6   0
```

MultiIndex is very handy for selection and grouping. Here are some examples:

```
agg_df['col2']  # select the second column
      max  min       std
col1                    
1       5    1  1.581139
2       9    0  3.535534

agg_df[('col2', 'max')]  # select the maximum of the second column
Out: 
col1
1    5
2    9
Name: (col2, max), dtype: int64

agg_df.xs('max', axis=1, level=1)  # select the maximum of all columns
Out: 
      col2  col3
col1            
1        5    -1
2        9     0
```

Earlier (before [version 0.20.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming)) it was possible to use dictionaries for renaming the columns in the `agg` call. For example

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg({'max_col2': 'max'})
```

would return the maximum of the second column as `max_col2`:

```
      max_col2
col1          
1            5
2            9
```

However, it was deprecated in favor of the rename method:

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(['max']).rename(columns={'max': 'col2_max'})

      col2_max
col1          
1            5
2            9
```

It can get verbose for a DataFrame like `agg_df` defined above. You can use a renaming function to flatten those levels in that case:

```
agg_df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in agg_df.columns]

      col2_max  col2_min  col2_std  col3_size  col3_std  col3_mean  col3_max
col1                                                                        
1            5         1  1.581139          5  1.581139         -3        -1
2            9         0  3.535534          5  3.535534         -6         0
```

For operations like `groupby().summarize(newcolumn=max(col2 * col3))`, you can still use agg by first adding a new column with `assign`.

```
df.assign(new_col=df.eval('col2 * col3')).groupby('col1').agg('max') 

      col2  col3  new_col
col1                     
1        5    -1       -1
2        9     0        0
```

This returns maximum for old and new columns but as always you can slice that.

```
df.assign(new_col=df.eval('col2 * col3')).groupby('col1')['new_col'].agg('max')

col1
1   -1
2    0
Name: new_col, dtype: int64
```

With `groupby.apply` this would be shorter:

```
df.groupby('col1').apply(lambda x: (x.col2 * x.col3).max())

col1
1   -1
2    0
dtype: int64
```

However, `groupby.apply` treats this as a custom function so it is not vectorized. Up to now, the functions we passed to `agg` ('min', 'max', 'min', 'size' etc.) are vectorized and these are aliases for those optimized functions. You can replace `df.groupby('col1').agg('min')` with `df.groupby('col1').agg(min)`, `df.groupby('col1').agg(np.min)` or `df.groupby('col1').min()` and they will all execute the same function. You will not see the same efficiency when you use custom functions.

Lastly, as of version 0.20, `agg` can be used on DataFrames directly, without having to group first. See examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43586132/2285236).

Answer (score 8):

It is very easy to transition your R code into python code without learning APIs of pandas using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar import f
>>> from datar.tibble import tibble
>>> from datar.dplyr import group_by, summarize
>>> from datar.base import min, max
>>> data = tibble(
...     col1=[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
...     col2=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
...     col3=[-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,0]
... )
>>> data >> group_by(f.col1) >> summarize(col2_agg=max(f.col2), col3_agg=min(f.col3))
   col1  col2_agg  col3_agg
0     1         5        -5
1     2         9        -9
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.

Comment: Trying to run that small toy example but getting an error: `TypeError: summarise() missing at least one argument.`

Comment: @GabrielMontenegro Mind submitting an issue (https://github.com/pwwang/datar/issues) to the repo with your code?

Answer (score 2):

Check the side-by-side comparison given by Pandas documentation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_r.html#grouping-and-summarizing

R's dplyr

```
gdf <- group_by(df, col1)
summarise(gdf, avg=mean(col1, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Pandas

```
gdf = df.groupby('col1')
df.groupby('col1').agg({'col1': 'mean'})
```