# Dataframe - type,length print

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I need to get a summary of the dataframe which would include it's 
Dataframe name
Datatype of the col
Length of the col
Label of the col

How would I achieve this in one go

Comment: please show us your code or a example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate summary statistics of columns in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235245/calculate-summary-statistics-of-columns-in-dataframe)

Comment: This should work `df.describe()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
my_df.head()
```

in order to get in touch with the firsts bunch of lines related to your data.

You can query your dataframe information using the following command:

```py
my_df.describe()
```

You can query the dimension of the dataframe using the following command:

```py
my_df.shape
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @alessiosavi answer, you can use

```
my_df.info()
```

> This method prints information about a DataFrame including the index dtype and column dtypes, non-null values and memory usage

[link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following to display the information of your dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
""" Creating a Data frame """
x = np.random.random(size=(10,5))
df = pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['c1','c2','c3', 'c4','c5'])
```

*printing the Dataframe information **df.info()***

```
""" Showing the information about the DF"""
df.info(verbose=True)
==>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 5 columns):
c1    10 non-null float64
c2    10 non-null float64
c3    10 non-null float64
c4    10 non-null float64
c5    10 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(5)
memory usage: 480.0 bytes
```

*printing the Dataframe's Stats info **df.describe()***

```
df.describe()
==>
c1         c2         c3         c4         c5
count  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000
mean    0.419097   0.420075   0.556356   0.504391   0.661001
std     0.274248   0.296394   0.362951   0.301068   0.292727
min     0.017923   0.059288   0.071882   0.008450   0.074783
25%     0.271136   0.128142   0.205978   0.353544   0.544547
50%     0.365274   0.447738   0.643339   0.510274   0.649837
75%     0.547394   0.616438   0.837924   0.710374   0.897682
max     0.987060   0.936498   0.990641   0.949928   0.993214
```